# Regex and powershell: Parse long string for specific guids

Tags: .net, regex, powershell

I have a 2000 line string, which I need to parse. The biggest part of the string is paths (C:\ etc) which I don't care about. I need to get from only the *** WRITER "Microsoft Hyper-V VSS Writer"** 2 things:

1) The Writer ID   = {66841cd4-6ded-4f4b-8f17-fd23f8ddc3de}

2) For each **Component** inside this **specific** writer (Microsoft Hyper-V VSS Writer), I need the name, which is also a guid. For example the first component is: **- Name: 02E98059-C043-421D-96BD-C19B193E2961**

My attempt is:

```
[Regex]::Match(input, @"(?is)\* WRITER ""(Microsoft Hyper-V VSS Writer)""\s*-\s*Writer\s*ID\s*=\s*[{(]?(?<WriterID>[0-9A-F]{8}[-]?(?:[0-9A-F]{4}[-]?){3}[0-9A-F]{12})[)}]?(?:.*?\n[\t\p{Zs}]{3,}\+\s*Component ""\1:\\(?<CompID>[^""]+))*");
```

Because the string to parse is quite long, I have created a regex 101 and here is the link: https://regex101.com/r/UzfR1f/1

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier to dump it to a file in my opinion. Then:

```
$getNext = $false
$fileContents = Get-Content File.txt
foreach($line in $fileContents){
    if($getNext){
        $line
        $getNext = $false
    }
    if($line -like '*"Microsoft Hyper-V VSS Writer*'){
        $getNext = $true
    }
}
```

You may need to parse the actual guids out but I output the whole line so you could see which is which.

Comment: The things is: This gets me all the Writer ID's, which is not what I want. I need only the Writer Id of the * WRITER "Microsoft Hyper-V VSS Writer", and the Name property of all components within it, which are guids too.

Comment: Aaah...I misunderstood. One minute.